# I need to display only part of web page on android web view but I couldn't do with using Jsoup

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I need display only specific part of web page on my webview and I tried it using Jsoup but selected part is display without java-script functionality and CSS styles. Jsoup display specified part but just only HTML elements and I can do nothing with it.

Can I do with zoom ? then how can I set initial zoom for specific area and I need to disable zoom option for users because if they adjust zoom then other part of web page will display.

[image: I need webview look like this]

[image: But actual full page is looks like this]

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by iFrame (HTML) , No neet to use Jsoup Also, Jsoup is exclusively made for data scraping.

Find out more here : [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Just make a html file in /assets folder in android studio and load that file in web view and you are done!